# Load > 2, does it matter?

Tags: process, backup, load

I see the following load on one of our servers

`load average: 2.08, 2.09, 2.03`

Is it too much and should be handled or can I just leave it? The server is a backup server with no direct usage, it should just run in the background.

Running top I see that some of our own processes are the hogs.

```
top - 09:37:53 up 97 days, 11:01,  1 user,  load average: 1.93, 2.04, 2.01
Tasks:  97 total,   4 running,  93 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  27.7% user,  72.3% system,   0.0% nice,   0.0% idle
Mem:    515468k total,   457544k used,    57924k free,    47684k buffers
Swap:   401584k total,    21372k used,   380212k free,   309444k cached

      PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND            
    11873 root      18   0  2784 2004 1984 R 49.7  0.4 425616:43 store_ss7_stats    
      969 root      18   0  2784 2004 1984 R 49.3  0.4 428211:12 store_ss7_stats    
        1 root       8   0   488  460  436 S  0.0  0.1   0:36.93 init               
        2 root       9   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:10.43 keventd            
        3 root      19  19     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:06.97 ksoftirqd_CPU0     
        4 root       9   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:32.55 kswapd             
        5 root       9   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:00.00 bdflush            
        6 root       9   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0   0:01.23 kupdated           
        8 root       9   0     0    0    0 S  0.0  0.0  22:44.93 kjournald          
      665 root       9   0   640  632  532 S  0.0  0.1 145:39.35 syslogd            
      668 root       9   0   544  448  408 S  0.0  0.1   6:31.40 klogd              
      672 postgres   8   0   916  756  704 S  0.0  0.1   0:16.70 postmaster         
      697 postgres   9   0  2000  828  812 S  0.0  0.2   0:02.20 postmaster         
      698 postgres   9   0  1060  892  760 S  0.0  0.2   0:02.13 postmaster         
      706 Debian-e   8   0   928  708  668 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.02 exim4              
      711 root       9   0   404  360  360 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 inetd              
      720 root       9   0  1364 1132 1096 S  0.0  0.2   0:00.03 sshd               
      724 daemon     9   0   632  556  540 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.00 atd
```

Comment: It seems that your server uses 100% of processor. It shouldn't be that way, espacially if it's backup server. If it have to actually work as primary server it might not be as efficient as you expect

Comment: Having load 2 mean you have for some interval two running processes (in average). But check what `store_ss7_stats` do and what can be the reason this process consume so much processor power.